# Add iOS 7 code to iOS 6 project

Tags: ios, objective-c

**I Understand TTS is only available in iOS 7** Before down vote please read through.

One of my customers want to add text-to-speech feature to existing project based on iOS 6. I understand in iOS 7 we have built in TTS so I want to use it.

The following code is working fine when project is based on iOS 7.

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Please raise my salary!!!"];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

But I am not able to add this code to existing project based on iOS 6.

I am using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542480/what-are-the-common-use-cases-for-iphone-os-version-max-allowed) way. Am I missing something? Or this built in TTS is something different stuff?

Comment: "Available in iOS 7.0 and later."

Comment: How can you use iOS 7.0 code in iOS 6.0?

Comment: Guys, he wants to include the code in the application, but make in _inaccessible_ when running iOS 6.0

Comment: The best you can do is test if the feature is available and only use it if it is.

Comment: @otiose - So what has he tried?

Comment: The question you reference discusses several different techniques.  It's impossible for us to guess which ones you tried.

Comment: @HotLicks I tried __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED, __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED, NSClassFromString, if([BLAH class])

Comment: @brianLikeApple _What_ isn't working? Is it building? Is it running, but crashing? Where is your failure?

Comment: That will not let you compile a single app that can run in either either environment.  You need to use a runtime test.

Comment: Show us some actual code.

Comment: If it's not even building, my guess is that you are building with the iOS 6 SDK. You can change that in the build settings. You will still need to do runtime checks to see if the functionality exists before using it.

Comment: @otiose I am getting error saying AVSpeechSynthesizer is not for armv7s.

Comment: @HotLicks I will add code soon.

Comment: @brianLikeApple Are you linking AVFoundation in your project?

Comment: When you get an error message, copy/paste the *exact* error message, and, where appropriate, include the section of code that the error refers to.  (In the compile error listing, right-mouse-click on the error message and select "show in log" to get a version of the message you can copy.)

Comment: @HotLicks sorry mate. otiose did find my problem. I am hoping give you up vote if you answer a question : ) It is my stupid fault. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to run code that cannot run on iOS 6, you need to have runtime checks that will make sure that you can run the code you are trying to run. A quick way to do this is to check if the class is available:

```
if([AVSpeechSynthesizer class]) {
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Please raise my salary!!!"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
} else {
    // Feature not available, do something else
}
```

You will need to do this regardless of whether or not the code compiles or not.

If your code is not even compiling correctly, then there are a few things you can check:

- Is your base SDK set to iOS 6.0?
- AVSpeechSynthesizer is part of AVFoundation - are you linking your project to it?

Comment: opps!, Yes, you are right. I did #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> but forget to add AVFoundation link to my project.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f ){

    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Please raise my salary!!!"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
//And an else block if you have a back-up plan
```

Comment: Have you tried it on your side? Yes, I know. It doesn't work from my side. otherwise I wouldn't ask such stupid questions.

Comment: This code cannot work, because AVSpeechSynthesizer requires iOS7 (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). This will only fix compile error on iOS6. You need to find an alternative way for OS's older than 7.

Comment: Your code is correct. So I give you up vote. But otiose found the point so I gave him accepted answer : )