# Continuing support for iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store-connect

I recently uploaded a test version of my app to iTunes Connect and the next day got this email:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "MyApp". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>   Missing 64-bit support -
>   Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store
>   must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning
>   June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same
>   requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the
>   default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a
>   single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.
>   After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader
>   to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

The last time I did a release I couldn't upload the app until I fixed the 64-bit build so I know that's okay, but I'm still building against the iOS 5 SDK because our app still supports it. If I change to build for the iOS 8 SDK will this stop my app working for older versions of iOS? How can I tell if new functionality will still work on iOS 5?

Comment: Ir you told me 6, but 5...

Answer (score 2):

You should always compile against the latest SDK, which is currently (3/2015) the iOS 8 SDK.

What you want to set is the "Deployment target". The deployment target specifies the lowest iOS version that you app claims to run on. The deployment target corresponds to the [__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542480/what-are-the-common-use-cases-for-iphone-os-version-max-allowed)  macro, btw.

So, you can compile against the iOS 8 SDK, and at the same time set the deployment target of the project to "5.0" (or "5.1", or whatever). You have to be careful though that you don't use iOS 8 functions when running on an iOS 5 device, because it would crash the app. I use the `-respondsToSelector:` method often to test for the availability of functions. +lots of looking into the docs. +lots of testing on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you update to iOS8 SDK, some of the functions will not work like Push Notification and Location Service. So you need to manage that part accordingly.