# iphone_os_version_max_allowed >= 90000 returns false in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, xcode6.3

I am developing an application using Google drive sdk, in Xcode 5 its working fine, but now I open it in xcode6 and write this code for Safariviewcontroller

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/SignUp"];
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
if (URL) {

    if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
        SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
        sfvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]) {
            NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[URL description]);
        }
    }
}
#else
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
#endif
```

but problem is in`Xcode6.3.1` `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` is `__IPHONE_8_3` and it always make it false. I tested in my iphone5c with `iOS9.2` but it always return False and got to the else part. please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See here for a discussion on [__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542480/what-are-the-common-use-cases-for-iphone-os-version-max-allowed)

Basically, as you mentioned, this is a question for Xcode, which is answered by it at compile time, not for your device. You should be instead doing a check one of the ways implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version).